# How to deal with Azure Web App deployment slot settings?

Tags: azure-deployment-slots

We are thinking about using deployment slots for Azure Web / Function Apps, but are struggling with one issue and would like to know your thoughts / solutions about this.
We think about doing the following:

1. Deploy IaC for a Web App
   a. IaC defines app settings for a slot (without 'deployment slot settings' enabled, because we want the setting to move to the destination slot when doing a swap)
   b. IaC includes slot1 (production)
   i.  key1: value1
   ii. key2: value2
   b. IaC includes slot2 (staging)
   i.  key1: value3
   ii. key2: value4
2. Deploy code to Web App slot 2 (staging)
3. Test Web App slot 2 (staging)
4. Swap slot2 and slot1, so slot1 will contain the latest code we deployed with they slot2 app settings, which means after the swap we will have the following:
   a. slot 1 (production)
   i.  key1: value3
   ii. key2: value4
   b. slot 2 (staging)
   i.  key1: value1
   ii. key2: value2

This looks great and is exactly what we want. But now when the IaC doesn't match with the status in Azure.

IaC contains:
b. slot1 (production)
i.  key1: value1
ii. key2: value2
b. slot2 (staging)
i.  key1: value3
ii. key2: value4

But Azure contains (after the swap):
a. slot 1 (production)
i.  key1: value3
ii. key2: value4
b. slot 2 (staging)
i.  key1: value1
ii. key2: value2

In a CI / CD pipeline, we don't want change IaC each time we do a deployment.

How do you cope with this issue?
How do you use deployment slots and swapping without having this issue?